# Cloud Custodian Report to extract AWS IAM Policies with specific actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, rule-engine, cloudcustodian

I'm new to cloud custodian and was wondering if cloud custodian can scan through the AWS IAM service - scan all the IAM policies for specific actions like S3Delete with Resoruce:*

If this can be done, how can we extract the results into a report?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see lines 30-38 of https://github.com/FireballDWF/securityhub-remediations/blob/master/module4/ec2-public-ingress-hubfinding.yml which is part of my Workshop for using AWS Security Hub with Cloud Custodian.  You can send findings from Cloud Custodian to AWS Security Hub, see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/announcing-cloud-custodian-integration-aws-security-hub/ for a introduction, then you can run a query in the Findings section of Security Hub.  If you need more help, I suggest you submit an issue on the my workshop requesting the help you are looking for and I'll try to answer in the form of an update to the workshop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
policies:
  - name: iam-user-policies
    description:  IAM USER policies 
    resource: iam-user
    filters:
      - or:
        - type: has-inline-policy
          value: true
        - type: policy
          key: PolicyName
          op: not-equal
          value: ""
        - type: PolicyStatement
          statements:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal: '*'
```